# ChatterBot Ubuntu Corpus Trainer

Tags: python, chatbot

Looking to create a custom trainer for chatterbot, In the ubuntu corpus trainer, it looks as if the training is done based on all the conversation entries. 
I manually copy the ubuntu_dialogs.tgz to the 'data' folder.
Trainer fails with error `file could not be opened successfully`

`https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/ubuntu_corpus_training_example.py`

can i unzip all the data to ubuntu_dialogs and provide to trainer?

**edit:** Yes, we can , the data folder is ".\data" , which is path from where you are invoking the ubuntu_corpus_training_example.py.
create a folder ubuntu_dialogs and unzip all the folders, the trainer.py looks at .\data\ubuntu_dialogs***.tsv files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can , the data folder is ".\data" , which is path from where you are invoking the ubuntu_corpus_training_example.py. create a folder ubuntu_dialogs and unzip all the folders, the trainer.py looks at .\data\ubuntu_dialogs***.tsv files